# How do I set values of variables that are in url with Objective c

Tags: php, objective-c

Hello I am trying to set the values of variables of a php file in objective c.  It works when I put the url in a browser.  But I am wondering on how to set the variables through objective c.
I know how to connect to a php file in objective c.  I believe this is how you set the variables but it isn't working.  I think it has to do with the variable having to have quotation marks in the url around it.
For example here:

```
http://localhost/MyPhpStuff/stuff/write.php?name="testName"&username="testUsername"&password="testPassword"


NSString *strURL = [NSString 
stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/MyPhpStuff/stuff/write.php?name=%@"
,nameTextField.text, "&username=%@", userNameTextField.text, 
"&password=%@", passwordTextField.text];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/MyPhpStuff/stuff/write.php?name=\"%@\"&username=\"%@\"&password=\"%@\"",nameTextField.text,userNameTextField.text,passwordTextField.text];
```

Comment: this didn't work for me I think its because the variables need quotation marks around them like seen in the example in my question.

Comment: Try adding quotes then: `NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/MyPhpStuff/stuff/write.php?name=\"%@\"&username=\"%@\"&password=\"%@\"",nameTextField.text,userNameTextField.text,passwordTextField.text];`